# CoreAudio: Is there any way to have active audio IO without preventing the system from sleeping?

Tags: macos, core-audio, sleep-mode

I'm the author of an open source macOS HAL audio driver that acts as a proxy for another output audio device. It currently has an issue where, when the audio driver is loaded, it prevents the system from sleeping.

This is because it is constantly receiving output from another audio device, and whenever a process has active audio IO using CoreAudio then that will prevent the system from sleeping.

Is there a way to do this and still allow the system to sleep?

Apple's CoreAudio documentation is quite lacking and so far I haven't found an answer to this on my own. I did find something interesting on one of the CoreAudio header files, the property `kAudioHardwarePropertySleepingIsAllowed` of the AudioSystemObject. However setting it to a value of 1 did not change things so that the system can sleep, and so it doesn't seem to solve this problem. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Hi! Have you been able to find the answer? I'm currently facing similar problem in my app

Comment: @mrvn Unfortunately no I haven't. At least for my audio driver, I worked around the issue by giving the user multiple options for how to deal with it. One of them involved detecting when the user was active (i.e. mouse and keyboard activity) and keeping the driver going during this time, rather than waiting for audio activity. But it's definitely an imperfect solution.

Comment: Hi @GuyGizmo, sorry for cross-posting on this question. I am down a similar pathway to build HAL Audio driver that is used as a proxy speaker device which when selected can apply some signal processing and route the audio to the Built-in speaker. I have a pretty good handle on the AudioServerPlugIn class to control the driver options but still struggling on how I can route the audio to a different device from the buffers I am receiving in `DoIOOperation()`. I thought about writing the buffers to a ringbuffer and streaming them over TCP. I'd really appreciate any suggestions you may have. Thx!

Comment: @avroshk I believe the "correct" way to do it, at least as far as Apple is concerned, is to receive the audio in a separate user-level process and then stream that audio to your desired audio device. One way to do that would be to have your driver provide both an input and output device, and have anything played to the output loop back to the input, similar to Soundflower. Then your user process can receive the audio from your HAL plugin's input.

Comment: @avroshk _That said_, I didn't actually do this in my own plugin because it would have been both a pain to implement and introduced additional latency. Instead I did something Apple quite explicitly says you're _not_ supposed to do and had my driver play the audio to the output device directly. I had it do so in a separate thread to avoid deadlocks. You can see how I did it in my project [Proxy Audio Device](https://github.com/briankendall/proxy-audio-device) on github if you wish.

Comment: @GuyGizmo Really appreciate you linking your project! It may not be the correct Apple way to do it for now but it helps take things forward! It makes sense that `allAudioDevices()` could be queried . I didn't think of that! This is great. 
Thanks!